# generics covariance and explicit casting

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

If I try and do:

```
IDictionary<uint, IEnumerable<string>> dict = new Dictionary<uint, List<string>>();
```

I get the error:

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary>'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

If I add the cast:

```
IDictionary<uint, IEnumerable<string>> dict = (IDictionary<uint, IEnumerable<string>>)new Dictionary<uint, List<string>>();
```

Then it compiles.

Why do I need the explicit cast? And is it safe? I thought the whole point on covariance was the ability to implicitly cast safely?

**EDIT:** 
C# prevents unrelated casting eg

```
string s = (string)0L;
```

> error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'long' to 'string'

It does allow explicit downcasting of related types when you know that the object is actually a subclass:

```
Animal animal = new Cat();
Cat cat = (Cat)animal;
```

I am confused why the compiler is offering, and allowing me to explicitly cast to an IDictionary with incompatible types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not safe.  For example, you could now write `dict.Add(5, new string[0])`, which would blow up, since a `string[]` is not a `List<string>`.  The fact that it is unsafe is why you need the cast.

Edit to address your updated concern:

C# allows any explicit cast from any reference type S to any interface T ("provided S is not sealed and provided S does not implement T.")  This behavior is specified in section 6.2.4 of the language spec.  So this is legal:

```
var foo = (IList<ICollection<IEnumerable<IntPtr>>>)new Uri(@"http://zombo.com");
```

I can't say why this is the case, other than the fact that the C# type system was originally even more constrained than it is today (e.g. no generics, no variance) so I'm sure that there were a lot of cases in which being able to hack around it with casts was very convenient.

Comment: I think I'm having a brain fart. Why does C# allow me to cast if the types are not compatible? Normally it forbids invalid casts. :/

Comment: @Gaz No, it doesn't. Explicit casts are pretty much always legal in the compiler because you're implying "Trust me, I know what I'm doing". They then blow up at runtime. Implicit casts are caught by the compiler, as you saw on the CS0266 above.

Answer (score 9):

`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not covariant, either for TKey or TValue.

Covariance would mean that IDictionary could solely produce TKey/TValue types, but since it can produce as well as consume them, it cannot be covariant, nor contravariant for that matter.

I'll define covariance / contravariance in common terms;

`IProducer<out T>` is covariant, so this means that it only produces T types. Thus when you pass it to a reference to an IProducer with a more **abstract** T, the cast is implicit, because the following statement is true: "A producer of apples IS a producer of fruit". (to be opposed to "A producer of fruit is not necessarily a producer of apples")

`IConsumer<in T>` is contravariant, which means in only consumes T types. When you pass it to a reference to a more **concrete** T, the cast is implicit, because the following statement is true: "A consumer of fruit IS a consumer of apples". (to be opposed to "A consumer of apples is not necessarily a consumer of any fruit")

What this means in the case of IDictionary, regarding specifically the TValue here:

IDictionary has methods that produce TValues as well as methods that consume TValues. That being said, it means it wasn't (and couldn't) declared as either covariant or contravariant. (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx - there is no "out" or "in" in the generic interface definition)

This means that when you try to implicitely cast your `Dictionary<uint, List<string>>` into an `IDictionary<uint, IEnumerable<string>>`, the compiler says "Wait a minute, the object you have built can only accept `List<string>` in an Add method but you're putting it into a reference that will allow any `IEnumerable<string>` in, which is a *larger* subset. If you Add anything that is an `IEnumerable<string>` but isnt a `List<string>`, it won't work." It doesn't (and can't) allow it implicitely, which is why you need the hard cast.

(thanks to mquander for the specific example)

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
     IDictionary<uint, IEnumerable<string>> dict = new Dictionary<uint, IEnumerable<string>>();
```

You are changing the TValue type in your code to a concrete List implementation. That will not work. you have to use the same definition as the declaring type.

With the above, you can use it as:

```
    dict.Add(1, new List<string>());
```

etc.